# Msgbus - How to subscribe to Properties Editor's context

Tags: python

I want to detect context changes when switching between different tabs in the property editor.

How should I set up msgbus or how to get the context through the Python API?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy

# Any Python object can act as the subscription's owner.
owner = object()

subscribe_to = bpy.types.SpaceProperties, 'context'


def msgbus_callback(*args):
    print(args)
    current_tab = bpy.context.screen.areas[0].spaces.active.context
    print(f'Current Tab: {current_tab}')


bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to,
    owner=owner,
    args=(1, 2, 3),
    notify=msgbus_callback,
)
```

Comment: oh , thanks !  I get it ！The  'subscribe_to'  should be  a combination of structure and property